# Delete strings with a specific last character in tibco spotfire

Tags: dataset, data-cleaning, data, preprocessing

I am using tibco spotfire and I have columns with data like this "0001V", "0002V", "0003N". I know data with the 'N' at the end is not valid so I need to delete the numbers which have that. I think I should use "limit data using expression" but I don't know how to write the expression. So it should be something like "if X ends in 'N' delete X"... Could you help me please?

Thanks!